# filtering wp_title() in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using this in header file of my site.

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

But it is displays '|' at the end of title on all the pages of site like this

```
<title>Our Company - SEO Company 1SEOIN |</title>
```

I want to remove this '|'. Please Help.

Comment: and what do you want as output?

Comment: @KrunalShah just this "Our Company - SEO Company 1SEOIN"

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

Please try with

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

It might be cause of crash with some of plugins.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
first to set your title on http://xxxx.com /wp-admin/customize.php

then heder.php in replace this 
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

to 
<title><?php wp_title( '', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the separator entirely, this how the WordPress codex suggests you call the wp_title function:

```
<title><?php wp_title('',true); ?></title>
```

Although I'd think this would be just as valid, since it uses TRUE for that parameter by default.

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

But, the first way is what WordPress suggests on their site, for whatever reason, so I would recommend the first method as "best practice".